# How to store multiple element into a var in js?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I store multiple element into the number var?

This is my code:

```
<div class="row1">
    <div class="number" id="number7"><br>
    <a href="" onclick="calculate(event)"><span>7</span></a></div>
    <div class="number" id="number4"><br>
    <a href="" onclick="calculate(event)"><span>4</span></a></div>
    <div class="number" id="number1"><br>
    <a href="" onclick="calculate(event)"><span>1</span></a></div>
    <div class="number" id="number0"><br>
    <a href="" onclick="calculate(event)"><span>0</span></a></div> 
</div>

<script>
function calculate(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var number = event.target.innerText;
    var total = document.getElementById('result');
    total.innerHTML=number;} 
</script>
```

Example: If I clicked the "7" 3 times, then the number var should have 3 "7" in it.

Comment: Well because you're putting the number into the result as a string you could simply add it to the end of itself like `total.innerHTML +=  number;`

Comment: @PatrickBarr Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
function calculate(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var number = event.target.innerText;
    var total = document.getElementById('result');
    total.innerHTML+=number;
}
```

```css
a,div{
  margin:0
}
```

```html
<div class="row1">
    <div class="number" id="number7">
    <a href="" onclick="calculate(event)"><span>7</span></a></div>
    <div class="number" id="number4">
    <a href="" onclick="calculate(event)"><span>4</span></a></div>
    <div class="number" id="number1">
    <a href="" onclick="calculate(event)"><span>1</span></a></div>
    <div class="number" id="number0">
    <a href="" onclick="calculate(event)"><span>0</span></a></div> 
</div>
<p id='result'></p>
```

This appends the characters to the innerHTML of the result element.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function calculate(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var number = event.target.innerText;
    var total = document.getElementById('result');
    //total.innerHTML+=number;
    total.textContent+=number;
}
```

```html
<div class="row1">
    <div class="number" id="number7"><br>
    <a href="" onclick="calculate(event)"><span>7</span></a></div>
    <div class="number" id="number4"><br>
    <a href="" onclick="calculate(event)"><span>4</span></a></div>
    <div class="number" id="number1"><br>
    <a href="" onclick="calculate(event)"><span>1</span></a></div>
    <div class="number" id="number0"><br>
    <a href="" onclick="calculate(event)"><span>0</span></a></div> 
    <br/>
    Result: <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

***EDIT***: instead of `innerHTML`, use `textContent` as if the selected text has some HTML tags or symbols, `innerHTML` will not return whole text, it will parse the text and returns the output.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a slightly different approach that makes this more scalable. In the example below you can add as many elements as you want that increase the total, depending on the value (innerText) of the clicked anchor element.

```
<div class="row1">
    <div class="number">
        <a href="" class="increase-number">1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="number">
        <a href="" class="increase-number">3</a>
    </div>
</div>
<span id="total"></span>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
    var total_increasers = document.getElementsByClassName('increase-number'); // All the anchor elements that can be clicked to increase the total.
    var total_counter = document.getElementById('total'); // The total counter element.

    Array.from(total_increasers).forEach(function(element) {
        element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var amount = parseInt(this.innerText); // The clicked number value as int.
            var current_total = parseInt(total_counter.innerText) || 0; // The current total as int.
            var new_total = current_total + amount; // The new total.

            total_counter.innerText = new_total;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```